# TDS Not Deploying Linked Files

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2013, tds

In a web project I added a few static assets as links to files that existed in the code so if they change in one place, they change in the other as well. This was a temporary hack because assets were being provided by someone else. once they were done I was going to add the files in the project instead of having them as links and remove them from the other place they currently exist. I'm pretty sure my problem is that TDS does not see files added as links. It looks like the references to the linked files show up only in the .csproj file and I'm pretty sure TDS deploys whatever physically exists in a project (or at least that's how it seems like it is working). Is there a way to get TDS to recognize files added as a link? I'm using TDS version 5.0.10 and Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the folder that was outside of the project to TDS's file replacement option in order to get it out.